# NSPredicate, NsNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, nspredicate, nsnumber

hi i have Core Data database with numerical attributes. they are NSNumbers. Default value is 0.0 but when i try to do some NSPredicated fetch, i get "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: nil RHS'" just because attribute value is 0.0

The predicate is created with:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %@) AND (endValue <= %@) AND (someId == %@)",startNSNumber,endNSNumber, idString]
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Please post how you're creating the predicate.

Comment: Please provide the code you use to make the predicate.

Comment: predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %@) AND (endValue < %@) AND (someId == %@)",startNSNumber,endNSNumber, idString]

Comment: maybe we need to have a bigger view of the problem to help, can you provide more lines of code: especially where startNSNumber, endNSNumber and iString come from?

Answer (score 5):

You're adding the floats as objects, not as floats? Try this :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %f) AND (endValue <= %f) AND (someId == %@)",startNSNumber,endNSNumber, idString];
```

Comment: `%f` is used for a `float` primitive.  `NSNumber` is an object (which means that `%@` is the correct substitution for it).

Comment: Blast, I misread the question and thought he was adding floats :( </shame>

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe one of your variables is nil or was autoreleased...

try this:

```
NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0];
NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0];
NSString *str = @"Test";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %@) AND (endValue <= %@) AND (someId == %@)", num1, num2, str];
```

If this succeeds that the problem is with your variables.

If you expect either `num1` or `num2` to be `nil` sometimes, then you could rewrite the predicate as:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %@) AND (endValue <= %@) AND (someId == %@)", num1 ? num1 : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], num2 ? num2 : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], idString];
```

Comment: yeah -.-' my problem is when num1 or num2 is [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] but this value is possible and necessary, but NSPredicate doesn't like it. throws exceptions. why?!

Comment: that is quite surprising, are you sure the variable is not `nil`? I've run a test code with a break point and `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]` generates a proper `NSNumber` object...

Answer (score 1):

Well, given the predicate you provided, the easy answer is:

Either `startNSNumber`, `endNSNumber` or `idString` is nil.  If you want to compare something against `nil` in an `NSPredicate`, you need to substitute in `[NSNull null]`, not `nil`.

Comment: so if (startNSNumber) {
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %@), startNSNumber]
} else {
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue => %@), [NSNull null]
}
?? will it be right ?!

Answer (score 0):

IN NSpredicate use string value as float the Dictionary key.floatValue and easily use.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startValue.floatValue => %f) AND (endValue.floatValue <= %f) AND (someId == %@)",startNSNumber,endNSNumber, idString]
```

I thing this post useful.